# Polymer global CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, polymer

TL;DR
**How can I define resources such as CSS/JS library global to use it in the Polymer components while they are working within their's shadow-roots?**

*Pre-history:*

I had two approaches to use CSS/JS in React-component in the prior project:

- Scripts or styles added from index.html are visible globally.
- Scripts or styles from inside the component using import statement are visible locally.

Now I have the project with Polymer, and I think my idea to have an ionicons.min.css visible globally is a good idea. So, I need it global.

Or the only way is to import them inside every component explicitly? Or maybe you know some best practices how to build the structure of components on Polymer, then share your experience, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i got bad news for you. Every Component has to import the style by itself and the styling has to be wrapped into a "styling module". See the [Documentation](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom#style-modules).

Comment: Still, we have libraries like momentjs we want to be available globally. Polymer proposes to encapsulate that all staff into the component. Although resource will be downloaded once it still required to be imported into every component. I like a component approach, but it seems to be kinda inconvenient. But if so I'll be agreed with that.